# How to check if a turtle is near a stamp using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

If a turtle gets near the coordinates in a list (like the one below) I want the code to return a True statement for a game in python. In my game the stamps are coins that you have to collect throughout the game. The list in the game has 10,000 coordinates so If you have a better idea for how to make the coin collection system then please tell me!

```
list_of_coords=[(150.0, -150.0),(50.0, -10.0),(-150.0, 0.0)]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague, but you can use Pythagoras' theorem to calculate distance between two points with Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: But that will work for one cord and if i will do a loop it will take ages because the real list has 10000 different values.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you could use the euclidian distance between two points (which basically simplifies into the Pythagora's theorem when in 2D).

Suppose you have your turtle coordinates like that (in the same format as the coordinates samples you provided, say (X,Y) in pixels) :

```
    turtle_coords = (10.0, 10.0)
```

You can write a function to compute the distance between the turtle and any other point (you could also use `sqrt` function from numpy package). This function takes the turtle coordinates (turtle_coords) as a couple (X_turtle, Y_turtle) and any point of interest coordinates (point_coords) again as a couple (X_point, Y_point). In these couples you can access each X value with couple[0] and Y value with couple[1]. The distance function is the following :

```
    def distance(turtle_coords, point_coords):
        return ((turtle_coords[0] - point_coords[0])**2 + (turtle_coords[1] - point_coords[1])**2)**0.5
```

You can then loop over all coordinates of your `list_of_coords` variable in order to create the list of distances between your turtle and each of your points of interest.

```
    distances = []
    for point_coords in list_of_coords:
        distances.append(distance(turtle_coords, point_coords))
```

You then have a list of distances between each one of provided coordinates and the turtle coordinates. You can then evaluate whether the turtle is close enough to some coordinates. Say you have a distance threshold :

```
    distance_threshold = 10   # Say 10 pixels
    close_to_coords = []
    for distance in distances:
        close_to_coords.append(distance <= distance_threshold)
        # You get a list like [False, False, True, False , etc...]
```

Comment: This is a simple answer, but please next time provide more information and code in order to get more accurate answers.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Well, if you know your turtle coordinates and the coordinates of each of your points of interest, then compute the distance between the turtle and each of your points of interest and only keep the ones that are closer than a given distance threshold (this is to say the ones that have a distance to the turtle smaller than the distance threshold).

Comment: But if I want to implement it to my code, I don't understand how.

Comment: For that you probably provided too little code. Please update your question with more of your code (even though you let an empty space where you are missing some code).

Comment: But please, can you explain the commands?

Comment: Okay, please be more accurate and tell which commands you don't understand.

Comment: Everything, I'm a begginer.

Comment: I edited the answer o make it more explicit

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
list_of_coords = [(150.0, -150.0), (50.0, -10.0), (-150.0, 0.0)]

def close_to_coord(coord):
    return turtle.distance(coord) < 10

if any(map(close_to_coord, list_of_coords)):
    # ...
```

Since `and` and `map` are lazy evaluated, this should stop processing `list_of_coords` as soon as it finds a near one.

Comment: Please can you explain you doing? I don't understand that code:(

Comment: If I want to implement it to my code I need to know more.